# Django-based app might grow out of control - how can I scale it?

Tags: django, apache, caching, scalability

I need some guidance in the realm of server architecture for Django.

My current Django-based web app stats (reached in two weeks - run on one VPS w/ Apache, mod_wsgi, mysql):

- 10,000 users total
- 20 avg requests/user/day
- 200,000 requests/day
- 8,000 users access site daily

Where the app could reach (where I'd be panicking - this assumes approx linear growth):

- 200,000 users total
- 20 avg requests/user/day
- 4,000,000 requests/day
- 160,000 users access site daily

The issue here is really just handling page requests. I only store short strings of text-based data, so DB size shouldn't be an issue.

What sort of server architecture should I be setting up from a hardware and software perspective? I need to think about caching, load balancing, multiple processing servers, multiple DB servers, etc, but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're projected growth of ~45 / requests per second really isn't that intensive.  I think using a standard nginx load balancer in front of your web servers will handle everything.  If your DB access isn't very intense you will probably do fine with just 1 DB machine.

I really think the most important thing is not to do any premature optimization.  Deal with issues as they come, or else you may end up wasting a lot of time.

There are tons of caching, multiple server configurations, and load balancing tutorials.

Google is a good place to start.

Growing traffic is a standard problem, there are no lack of tutorials on these things.